# Send Image (Bitmap/File) Intent Android

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap

I am developing 2 applications one for send image and the other for receive it. I have the same problem sending the image file or the Bitmap.
I already read lot of Q&A here but nothing help.

1st App Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application ...>
    <activity ...>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

1st App class ( using Bitmap )

```
try {
        //Write file
        String filename = "bitmap.png";
        FileOutputStream stream = this.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

        //Cleanup
        stream.close();
        bitmap.recycle();

        //Pop intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra("image", filename);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

2nd App Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application ...>
    <activity ...>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

2nd App class

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            String filename = intent.getStringExtra("image");
            try {
                FileInputStream is = this.openFileInput(filename);
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                is.close();
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

The error always have, when i try to send uri from file i take same error.
(I think is because i can't open file in 2nd application but i don't know how open it, i tried to save and open in so many places but nothing help)

```
03-22 14:52:05.412 1286-1818/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=image/* cmp=com.example.k.handleintents/.MainActivity (has extras)} from uid 10064 on display 0
03-22 14:52:05.467 3069-3069/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.example.k.handleintents/files/bitmap.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-22 14:52:05.467 3069-3069/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
03-22 14:52:05.467 3069-3069/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
03-22 14:52:05.467 3069-3069/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:384)
03-22 14:52:05.468 3069-3069/? W/System.err:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:177)
03-22 14:52:05.468 3069-3069/? W/System.err:     at com.example.jorgealberto.handleintents.MainActivity.handleSendImage(MainActivity.java:85)
03-22 14:52:05.468 3069-3069/? W/System.err:     at com.example.jorgealberto.handleintents.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
03-22 14:52:05.468 3069-3069/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
03-22 14:52:05.468 3069-3069/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
03-22 14:52:05.468 3069-3069/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
03-22 14:52:05.468 3069-3069/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
03-22 14:52:05.468 3069-3069/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
03-22 14:52:05.468 3069-3069/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
03-22 14:52:05.468 3069-3069/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-22 14:52:05.468 3069-3069/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
03-22 14:52:05.468 3069-3069/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
03-22 14:52:05.469 3069-3069/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-22 14:52:05.469 3069-3069/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
03-22 14:52:05.469 3069-3069/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-22 14:52:05.469 3069-3069/? W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-22 14:52:05.469 3069-3069/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
03-22 14:52:05.469 3069-3069/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
03-22 14:52:05.469 3069-3069/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
03-22 14:52:05.469 3069-3069/? W/System.err:    ... 17 more
03-22 14:52:05.584 3069-3083/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-22 14:52:05.584 3069-3083/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabe633a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-22 14:52:06.188 1286-1305/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.example.jorgealberto.handleintents/.MainActivity: +754ms
```

Comment: Does the app have the permissions required to access that file? If it's another app and the file is stored in the internal app-only storage it prolly won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `openFileInput()` points to an app's own portion of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Hence, `openFileInput()` of the first app points to a different location than does `openFileInput()` of the second app.

Second, files in internal storage for an app are private for that app. Your second app has no rights to access the file from the first app.

Instead, you need to use [some sort of `ContentProvider`, such as `FileProvider`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/16/how-publish-files-via-content-uri.html), to make the files available to third-party apps. This is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html).

Comment: Thanks the privacy was the problem.